# XSLT 1.0 Forcing datatype to be nodeset

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

XSLT 2.0 allows one to force an empty parameter to be of a certain datatype. XSLT 1.0 doesn't. (Right?) But I need to force an empty parameter to be a nodeset, so that I can later add nodes to it.

Passing the 0th node of a nodeset appears to work:

`<xsl:with-param name="topofstack" select="$nodesetB[0]" />`

But is it legal? guaranteed to work? Is there a "correct" way to force an empty parameter to be a nodeset in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to force an empty parameter to be a nodeset, so that I can
>   later add nodes to it.
>
> Passing the 0th node of a nodeset appears to work:
>
> ```
> <xsl:with-param name="topofstack" select="$nodesetB[0]" />
> ```

**I use the much shorter**:

```
/..
```

Answer (score 0):

> so that I can later add nodes to it

Well, values and variables in XSLT are immutable, so this doesn't make much sense.

However, it's certainly possible to pass an empty node-set as the value of a parameter, and as Dimitre says, the accepted convention for doing this is "/.."; I have also been known to use "@comment()", though some processors produce warnings if you write this.

Comment: I misspoke. "...so that I can later UNION it with another node set."